# previousPage.buffer throws httpException

Tags: asp.net, postbackurl

I have an asp.net 4 app with 2 forms. in first form I have

```
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save"     onclick="Save_Click"PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" />
```

. In second page I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "you came from site: " + PreviousPage.Title;
        }
    }
```

but title is empty. previousPage.buffer throws httpException "response is not available in this context" with ErrorCode = -2147467259. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is bother me is that you have type "you came from site". Don't you make post from the same site but on different pages ?. If you make post on different sites then the validation will fail and you can not get the title or other data from previous page.

Comment: It is an example from apress asp.net 4 book. Now I have checked query string: it also does not work, so I believe that may be something wrong with my PC configuration.

Comment: do you call that inside an updatePanel ?